# Why is the default width for a MySQL signed MEDIUMINT 9 instead of 8?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, mysql-5.6

If I create a signed `MEDIUMINT` column without a width specifier, MySQL automatically adds a width of 9. However, the range of a signed `MEDIUMINT` is -8388608 to 8388607, which only needs 8 display characters max including the sign.

I tested all the other `*INT` types without a width and the default width MySQL assigned matched the worst case maximum number of characters needed to output the datatype. Why does a signed `MEDIUMINT` default to +1 character?

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/integer-types.html

Comment: do you mean that in Mediumint data type , instead of having width 9 , it displays character only upto 7 and one is for signed but in INT data type (which is 11)  it display 10 digits and 1 is for signed . so you are asking why mediumint is having one extra character ? Do you mean this ?

Comment: Yes. My app is comparing a MySQL-reported schema against a reference schema without length, so I was just wondering why MySQL has an extra length for `MEDIUMINT` that what appears necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm... Sounds like a bug.  But since that number is not used for *anything* (assuming you don't have `ZEROFILL`), then it is no big deal.

You could, if you like, file a bug report at bugs.mysql.com .

Comment: You are right. And there was already a [bug report](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=69042) for it. Thanks.

Comment: Bug report is 4 years old; obviously no urgency.

Comment: True. I left a comment on it anyway as it seems like an easy fix. The last bug I reported for MySQL took almost 4 years to close, but someone eventually took care of it.